# Open Json object в HTML by JQuery. Asp.Net Core

Tags: jquery, html, json, asp.net-core

First of all, I will show the early working version.

```
public dynamic Get()
{List<string> myHeadline = new List<string>();
    List<string> myBodyText = new List<string>();

    var s = db2.Post.ToList();

    foreach (var item in s)
    {
        myBodyText.Add(item.BodyText);
        myHeadline.Add(item.Headline);
    }

    var result = new { data1 = myHeadline, data2 = myBodyText};

    return result;
}
```

And the code of frontend

```
 function getData(data) {
var url = "/api/Blog"
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data1.length; i++) {
        $("#idfirst").after('<div id="post' + i + '" class="post">' +
            '<div id = "posthead' + i + '" class= "posthead"></div>' +
            '<div id="postbody' + i + '" class="postbody"></div>' +
            '<div id="imgPost' + i + '" class="imgPost"></div></div>');

        $("#posthead" + i).append($('<p>').text(data.data1[i]));
        $("#postbody" + i).append($('<p>').text(data.data2[i]));


      });
     }

      $(document).ready(function () {
       getData();
       })
```

Everything is working. All posts from database writing on HTML.

I decided to add photos and make return object such as one file JSON. The main code I will not show cuz I don't see the sense on it. The object I build from the class where are the three Properties. Code:

```
public class GetBlogPost
{
public GetBlogPost()
{

}

public GetBlogPost(string Head, string Body, List<string> imgPost )

{
    this.Headline = Head;
    this.BodyText = Body;
    this.Img64 = imgPost;
}

public string Headline { get; set; }

public string BodyText { get; set; }

public List<string> Img64 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I add all complete object of this class to the collection

```
List<GetBlogPost> resultPost = new List<GetBlogPost>();
mypost = new GetBlogPost(postFromBase[i].Headline, postFromBase[i].BodyText, 
myPostImg);
resultPost.Add(mypost);
```

And convert to JSON

```
var result2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultPost);
return result2;
```

And here I don't want to open on HTML my JSON object.
I tried all cases and combinations. Maximum what it has it [object, object] on HTML.

For Example, I tried such

```
<script>
function getData(data) {
    var url = "/api/Blog"
    window.alert("Hello World")
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#idfirst").after('<div id="post' + i + '" class="post">' +
                '<div id = "posthead' + i + '" class= "posthead"></div>' +
                '<div id="postbody' + i + '" class="postbody"></div>' +
                '<div id="imgPost' + i + '" class="imgPost"></div></div>');

            $("#posthead" + i).append($('<p>').text(data[i].Headline));
            $("#postbody" + i).append($('<p>').text(data[i].BodyText));
        }
    });
   }

    $(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
})
```

In VS on break point on "return result2" it shows normal JsonFile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeeV1.png)

I read that there is a  $.parseJSON(d);  How I can implement it on my page I maybe I do some wrong on HTML? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it is working with $.getJSON

```
<script>
function getData(data) {
    var url = "/api/Blog"
    $.getJSON(url, function (data)
    {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            $("#idfirst").after('<div id="post' + i + '" class="post">' +
                '<div id = "posthead' + i + '" class= "posthead"></div>' +
                '<div id="postbody' + i + '" class="postbody"></div>' +
                '<div style="width:100%;" id="imgPost' + i + '" class="imgPost"></div></div>');

            $("#posthead" + i).append($('<p>').text(obj[i].Headline));
            $("#postbody" + i).append($('<p>').text(obj[i].BodyText));

            if (obj[i].Img64.length > 0)
            {
                var x = obj[i].Img64.length;

                for (var y = 0; y < x; y++)
                {
                    $("#imgPost" + i).append('<img alt="img" class="imgPost" style="margin:10px;" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + obj[i].Img64[y] + '" />');
                }
            }  
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    getData();
})
```